# Cheapest way to commute from Gravesend to London Bridge via public transport

Tags: uk, trains, london, return-tickets

I need to commute on public transport from **Gravesend to London Bridge** 3-5 times a week during peak hours (**arrive 9am, leave 5pm**), but I'm unsure of what the cheapest way to do this would be as there are too many options to compare, such as Season Tickets, Railcards, Oyster Cards, or just buying an annual ticket.

I'm 20, so if the 18-25 Railcard is the cheapest I am able to get that.

Comment: If this is your daily commute, there may be more considerations than just price. Convenience, overall time, ability to use time productively, etc. Cheapest would be to bike: 2.5 hours each way and you don't have to go to the gym anymore.

Comment: @Hilmar While I would love to cycle there, I'd need to leave at 6:30am and I'd probably arrive at work very sweaty haha! My main concern is the price, but if a certain route is considerably quicker/more convenient and is only a little bit more expensive I don't mind that.

Comment: This question and the first two comments (particularly the second sentence of the second comment) illustrate perfectly how "What's the cheapest" or "What's the fastest" queries decline into long discussions as the OP realizes that isn't actually what they want. The real question is almost never "the cheapest" or "the fastest," but instead is "What I like" or "What works for me" or "What is most convenient." I voted to close.

Comment: Okay, so cheapest way there by train, but if there is a faster route that is say 5-10% more expensive I don't mind doing that route. However, the question is meant to be more so focused towards Season Tickets vs. Railcards vs. Oyster Cards, etc. as they all have different terms to them which I find really confusing.

Comment: Is London Bridge actually your final destination or do you need to go to a different place in London? It is slightly faster (but less convenient and more expensive) to take the High-Speed service to Stratford International or Saint Pancras and change to get to London Bridge, but for some other destinations in London it is much quicker and not less convenient. Likewise, do you need to use public transport (like a bus) to get to/from Gravesend train station?

Comment: @Hilmar fares will vary based on the use of high speed services, Peak/Off-peak, and possibly advance purchase (and maybe more).

Comment: @jcaron: unfortunately also on how provides the service and even on which website you look

Comment: @jcaron The final destination is only a 5 min walk round the corner from London Bridge, which I'm more than happy to do. I will likely be taking a bus to get to Gravesend train station, I've figured the best price for that would be getting the "Adult 12 Day Bundle Gravesend" or the 4-week/annual ticket.

Comment: I’m way too lazy to write a full answer but there’s the option of Redwing Coaches’ 735 bus, possibly coupled with the 490 and/or Jubilee. Could be a lot cheaper, but it also takes quite a bit more time.

Answer (score 3):

That's a fairly complicated question. "Cheapest" would probably be biking, but this may not be acceptable to you (although it is to some people).

If you look at train tickets, there are indeed a large number of options and "cheapest" depends on you exact details and preferences.

Factors that impact the prices are

1. Can you travel off-peak? Before 7am or slight after 9am?
2. Do you want to use high speed rail ?
3. Do you want just the commute or general London travel include ?

You also have to be pretty precise of what your commute schedule will be. 3 times a week is VERY different from 5 times per week. Do you do work travel (being gone for a week at a time)? do you typically take off a month or so in summer?

The best way to go about this is to make a spreadsheet of all the different options and rate them according to your preferences and cost them out based on your anticipated usage pattern.  Yes, that's a couple of hours of work but you are looking at maybe £4000 per year, so this may be a good investment of your time,

Major options are

1. Thameslink
2. National Railway

Thameslink pricing for no high speed, no London, peak hours (most flexible) is

- Daily: £28.40
- Weekly: £97.80 or 3.4 days
- Monthly: £375.60 or 3.8 weeks or 13.2 days
- Yearly: £3912.00 or 10.4 months, 40 weeks, 138 days

The also have an interesting option of a Flex ticket, which is 8 day passes for roughly £25 each to be used with 28 days. That can be interesting if you do 3 or less days a week.

I think I was able to make a 16-25 railcard work using this link: https://www.traintickets.com/search/?/results/155081/153623?departdate=2022-03-15T07:30:00&railcards=YNG%7C1&returndate=2022-03-15T17:00:00

This brought the daily down to £18.70 which could be a substantial savings. You may want to call up Thameslink to check whether the 16-25 railcard can be applied to their season tickets as well.

**Update based on the cycling discussion**

If you stick with railcard augmented anytime day tickets, you can mix and match to you heart's content. The railcard itself is only £30 (I think)

1. Gravesend to London is £18.70
2. Dartford to London is $12.70
3. Dartford is the first stop in London Zone 6, so if you want to do a bunch of outings in London as well you can pay London 1-6 anytime day pass for £14.10 instead

So if you are feeling active and the weather is nice, you can bike to Dartford and then take the train from there and if not, take the train from Gravesend.  Try that for a while and see how it goes.

If the season tickets can't be used with the railcard, than the railcars is probably the winner. The season tickets are only a winner if you are a very regular commuter, which these days is not that common anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! 

Off-Peak travel isn't an option, and high speed looks to be slower for me. I just need the commute into London.

I didn't know Flex tickets existed, though I don't think it has enough days unfortunately.
The idea of making a spreadsheet sounds like a great idea, I may do just that!

I came across the following link which says Railcards can't be used with Season tickets unfortunately:
https://www.16-25railcard.co.uk/using-your-railcard/travel-times-tickets/
Using it with anytime day tickets is £56/week for 3 days, so that looks the most promising!

Comment: I'm pretty certain railcards and season tickets never mix. I know a fellow commuter with a different railcard had to buy day tickets (she'd get a week's worth in one visit to the ticket office). What might be worth checking is railcards and flex tickets; while I use the latter, I'm not eligible for any railcards

Comment: Also I suggest that at least until working patterns settle down, there's no point committing to long term season tickets. With occasional days at home, very occasional work travel and a fairly generous holiday allowance, an annual ticket is of marginal  benefit over careful use of the shorter ones and day tickets anyway. National rail has a season ticket calculator but it does a bad job of edge effects, assuming that you'll only buy one ticket type and rounding up, thus considering 2 monthly seasons for traveling 1 month and 1 day. A few minutes can produce a better spreadsheet

Comment: Flex tickets BTW have a validity of 4 weeks but you can use them faster than that. On my route, they're better value for 4 days per week than a weekly ticket, so mine last only 2 weeks before running out of trips

Comment: @Chris H - UK - as always there is an exception to season tickets and railcards not mixing. The 16-17 saver Railcard railcard does give a discount on season tickets.

Comment: @skifans Always an exception.  But I think that product hasn't always been "railcard" branded and  TfW seem to market it as just "16-17 saver" even now (big poster at Cardiff Central at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

I the comments there's discussion of cycling.  I ride a lot, and I'd do that journey sometimes, but not every day.  But that does lead to a possibility.

However, if you're prepare to ride as far as Crayford (about an hour's ride), a day return drops from £28.40 to £16.  Dartford comes in at £19.30, and is about 15 bike minutes closer to Gravesend.  Compared to a longer ride, this should also be less sweaty.  There should be a toilet on the train where you can get changed - I've often done this on my bike+train commute.

Both have bike parking, apparently with shelters. You'd need a good lock and to remove lights, etc., but I've done something similar daily in Bristol for the last few years.

There should be flex and railcard options comparable to the ones in Hilmar's answer from these stations as well, but in general in London, if you can start a zone or two closer, you can save quite a lot.

Comment: BTW if you rode a direct route all the way, you'd pass the road I grew up in - a long time ago.

Comment: Wow, that's a big difference in price! Would it not be difficult to fit the bike onto the train during peak times? It gets pretty crammed in there. Interestingly the full journey time doesn't seem to be that much longer when cycling part of the way, which isn't what I expected.

Comment: @Kieran I was assuming you'd leave the bike at the station, unless you can get a folding bike.

Comment: @Willeke both apparently have bike parking with shelters (42 spaces at Crayford, 64 at Dartford). Very few UK stations lack bike parking at all,though unfortunately for me, one that does provides a useful alternative when my normal line is closed.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK Unfortunately I've had a bike stolen from one of these shelters before, only to report it and not hear anything back, so I'm unsure if I should trust one again

Comment: @Kieran what locks do you use?  I always use a D-lock.  Sold secure silver rated for my hybrid, and gold-rated for my tourer.  Locked through the chainstays and rear wheel so both the frame and wheel are secured  But if I only had a shiny carbon road bike I'd think twice. Cable locks are only worth having to secure the other wheel.  The savings in a month in this case would pay for a 2nd hand hybrid plus a decent lock.  The savings in a week would pay for a decent lock.  Also look into Bike Register, which marks the bike quite obviously.  Local police often offer free marking, otherwise ££

Comment: @ChrisH-UK I have a lock from Kryptonite (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B06XCLTVPQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1), also bought an extra one of the cables to be safe. Got some stickers on too to say it's GPS tracked. I wasn't aware Bike Register sold marking kits, how permanent are they actually? Can the stickers not be pulled off?

Comment: @Kieran you know the cable isn't up to much, don't you? The lock body needs to connect the bike to something solid with the cable only securing extras.  The bike register stickers can probably be removed, and they probably leave a mess when they are.  But the main part of the marking is permanent paint which isn't coming off without a fair bit of sanding, damaging at least the paintwork. The serial number is also logged as part of the process, making recovery and prosecution easier (if you're lucky and live somewhere bike thieves actually get prosecuted, as I do).

Comment: ... [This](https://thebestbikelock.com/best-u-lock/kryptonite-kryptolok-series-2-review/) is the less good one I keep on my hybrid), and [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Master-hardened-u-lock-shackle-diameter/dp/B00511NBK4?tag=thebestbikelo-21&geniuslink=true) the better one I use with my tourer when commuting